# Error with PDF scraping using Tabulizer library

Tags: java, pdf, extract, tabulizer

I'm trying to extract tables from several pdf files and used the Tabulizer library. However, as I use the extract_tables function, I keep getting this error:
**Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  :
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class RJavaTools cannot access a member of class java.util.ArrayList$Itr (in module java.base) with modifiers "public"**.
I have macOS Big Sur(M1, 2020) and have the latest version of Java and R installed. I would appreciate any help and guidance.
Here is the code that I used:

library(tabulizer)
library(rJava)                                                                                           library(pdftools)
setwd(file.path(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path),'Input Files'))

pdf_files<- list.files(pattern = ".pdf$")

pdf_joined<- pdf_combine(pdf_files,output = "joined.pdf")
f <- "joined.pdf"

out1 <- extract_tables(f)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sure. Just included the code that I wrote as well.